# Mock class object as parameter of function

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am using junit and mokito to write unit test of my java program.

```
public MyClass {
    private ClassA a;
    public void process(ClassB b) {
        if(b.method()) a = ClassA.builder().build();

    }
}
```

Now I have write a MockClassA and MockClassB. But I don't know how to :

1. Pass a MockClassB instantiation to process function
2. How to verify whether private variable a is set successfully

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
@Test
public void shouldDoSomething() {
    // given
    ClassB mock = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.method()).thenReturn(true);
    MyClass classUnderTest = new MyClass();

    // when
    classUnderTest.process(mock);

    // then
    // Insert assertions

}
```

However, if your field is private you are unable to test it properly. You should provide a getter for this field if you want to make some assertions against it.

But remember that internal representation of `MyClass` should not be tested, only the behavior of it so maybe you want to try different approach